# Как находить одинаковые числа(элементы) из N числа файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

Есть алгоритм создания рандомных файлов с рандомными числами

```
from random import *

for i in range(randint(2,10)):
    with open(r"E:\result\file{}.txt".format(i), "w") as f:
        for a in range(i + 1): #Без + 1 один файл не заполняется
            list_1 = [randint(1,1000)for b in range(randint(1,10000))]
            f.writelines(str(list_1))
            
    with open(r"E:\result\file{}.txt".format(i), "r") as fil:
        print(fil.read())
```

Если к примеру сгенерируется 5 файлов и в каждом из них будет одинаковое(Рандомное) число,
то создать отдельный файл с названием result.txt в котором будут только эти одинаковые числа
как это осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все пояснения привел в виде комментариев в самом коде

```py
from random import *
from pathlib import Path

# определим путь до базового каталога
base_path = Path(r'path\to\folder')
# создадим пустой список для хранения содержимого всех файлов
all_contents = []
# определим количество итераций
iters = randint(2,10)
# определим список результатов
res = []

# ============================== ГЕНЕРАЦИЯ ДАННЫХ ==============================

# Укажите нижнюю границу генерируемого диапазона = 1. 
# К количеству итераций нужно прибавить 1, 
# так как верхняя граница не входит в диапазон.
for i in range(1, iters + 1):
    # сгенерируем название файла через f-строку
    fl_name = f'file{i}.txt'
    # используйте объекты Path для генерации путей
    # обязательно указывайте кодировку файлов, иначе могут быть неожиданности
    with open(base_path / fl_name, "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        # определим список для хранения содержимого всего файла
        fl_content = []
        for a in range(i):
            # сгенерируем содержимое куска файла
            chunck_content = [
                str(randint(1,1000)) 
                for b in range(randint(1,10000))
            ]
            # добавим его к содержимому всего файла
            fl_content += chunck_content
        # добавим содержимое файла к содержимому всех файлов
        all_contents.append(fl_content)
        # запишем содержимое файла, сгенерировав строку из списка с разделителем
        f.write(', '.join(fl_content))


# =================================== АНАЛИЗ ===================================

# присвоим результату содержимое первого файла
res = all_contents[0]
# обойдем содержимое всех оставшихся файлов в цикле
for content in all_contents[1:]:
    # на каждой итерации оставляем только те числа, 
    # которые встречались во всех предыдущих
    # Здесь списки приводят к множествам, которые поддерживают операцию
    # пересечения, результат снова приводим к списку
    res = list(set(res) & set(content))

# если длинна списка с результатами больше 0
if len(res) > 0:
    # записываем результат в файл
    with open(base_path / 'results.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fl:
        fl.write(', '.join(res))
```